# Selecting a useful codepage given a particular locale

Tags: java, character-encoding

Given a Locale in Java (eg. Locale.FRANCE) how can I pick a sensible code-page to accompany it for single-byte encoding?  I can get the language from the locale (eg. "fr") but then turning this into a code-page ("ISO-8859-1") seems tricky.  As I understand it the mapping isn't necessarily one-to-one, so at this point I'm simply trying to guess at something for a default option.

```
public static Charset guessSinglebyteCharsetFromLocale(Locale loc) {
    // ...
}
```

The use-case here is exporting a CSV file for use in Excel.  Excel doesn't appear to understand Unicode unless the user explicitly goes through the Data->Import Text wizard, and the requirement is for them to be able to open these files "as simple as possible".  In my system I know the Locale for the current user, so I want to automatically guess at a codepage that will mangle their data the least.

Comment: Would adding a Unicode BOM to the generated file help the hapless Excel users?  In my experience, writing a CSV Unicode text file but surreptitiously giving it an ".xslx" extension fools them all (but this foregoes any actually useful Excel features in the spreadsheet).

Comment: Good idea - tried it out and it works - Excel (at least the versions i have access to) now interprets the UTF8 files correctly.  Unfortunately, several other data tools have now choked on it instead.  BOMs don't seem to be particularly well supported.  I think this is certainly the lesser of the two evils, however.  Thanks.

Comment: It's quite possible that it will work fine even without the BOM, though you could end up with an import wizard when you least expect it, or incorrectly imported data.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no one-to-one java Locale to java Charset conversion available in Java. You will need to build a table of possible locale that your application expects to encounter.

For Excel to recognized the converted single byte text, your computer will need to be set to intended locale for 'non-unicode' applications using the Region/language settings from the Control Panel.  This also imposes another requirement, namely that only one locale can exist within one csv file.